# What is the correct type of anchor bolt for attaching a sill plate to a slab once the concrete is dry?

Tags: concrete, framing, code-compliance, foundation, hardware

If you need to install additional anchor bolts after the concrete has cured (and thus can no longer install traditional J bolts), what is the correct type of fastener that can be installed into dry concrete and is IRC 2012 compliant?

Comment: https://www.concretefasteners.com/diy-articles-anchoring-sill-plates-to-concrete

Comment: Talk to your AHJ. We use threaded rod, sunk a minimum of 8" and glued with something like Simpson Set-XP (2 part epoxy designed for structural uses). Other choices exist.